# TFS Build Definition Label Format

Tags: vbscript, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to add some logic to one of our TFS build definition's build label field.

Currently the settings look like this:

[image]

Note the custom fields Major Version Number and Previous Major Release Date. I want to modify the Build Number Format field so that the end result will be something like:

`<BuildDefinitionName> <Major Version Number>.<# Days since Previous Major Release Date [4 Digits]>.<Revision Number>`

so an example output would be:

`DebugBuild 6.0.0012.1`

Where `0012` would mean 12 days.

How can I accomplish this? I'm having trouble understanding where these `$(Var)` fields are declared as they seem to be separate from the Build process template variables and arguments while the Major Version Number and Previous Major Release Date arguments I've declared do exist in the build process template and are assigned to arguments `MajorVersionNumber` and `PreviousMajorReleaseDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is [customise the TFS build workflow](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) and add a custom **Code Activity** before the "Update Build Number" step.

This code activity takes in the `BuildNumberFormat` variable, replaces any of my custom tokens and passes out a result to my own `localBuildNumberFormat` variable. I then pass my `localBuildNumberFormat` to the "Update Build Number" activity.

So the process is something like:

- BuildNumberFormat = `$(CustomToken)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev:.r)`
- Input to Custom Activity = `$(CustomToken)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev:.r)`
- Output from Custom Activity = `DavesBuild_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev:.r)`
- Input to TFS Build Activity = `DavesBuild_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev:.r)`

You are essentially replacing all the tokens TFS cannot understand before passing it to TFS.

How you get the values for your Custom Token is up to you, you can pass them as arguments from the build definition/request, or look them up in the Code Activity (I do both in mine).

Comment: Ok I tried this solution. I have my custom Code Activity and I added a reference to the compiled .dll to my build controller but when I open my custom build process .xaml file my Code Activity isn't showing up in the Toolbox?

Comment: You should have a Solution with your XAML templates in one project with a reference to another project with your code activities. I also use the Wrox pro TFS books as a reference.